# Is it good idea to deliver desktop app with docker?

Tags: docker, lamp

I am interested in some good way to deliver desktop app to users.
The app is a web app made with LAMP, but I need and users to run it on desktop.
I want to choose some good cross platform solution for this.

I already have a docker image for this app.

Is there a practice to use docker to deliver apps to users? Like installation package that installs docker (if not installed yet) and than run a docker image.
Is there any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is not a good match for this use case.  My recommendation would be to choose a widely available scripting language like Python or JavaScript for the implementation and use an embedded database like SQLite for the persistence layer; then your end users only need to install the language interpreter (which they may already have) and your application and they can use the browser they already have for the front-end.

Docker presents a number of challenges here; if you browse around other [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) questions you can see people hitting some of them very routinely:

- On non-Linux, Docker running Linux applications requires a Linux VM, which turns "lightweight container system" into "full-blown resource-hogging virtual machine".
- On non-Linux, the set of host filesystem paths are accessible is limited.  Your application won't work if it's trying to access user data on a Windows F: drive, to pick one recent question.
- If your application manages some amount of "user" data, managing filesystem permissions is tricky and different on every OS.
- If your application tries to present a GUI, and you're trying to build "one portable image", then you're forced onto the Linux X11 platform; and that requires a matching X server on the host (an extra software install!), plus several extra finicky bind mounts, environment variables, and host settings.
- If your application tries to present a GUI, it can't by default access the user's non-Docker desktop preferences, and so it's likely to look and behave differently from a native application.
- Docker requires some amount of escalated privileges to run at all, and so if you have a security issue (especially in the machinery to launch the container which handles all of the above) it's much more likely to compromise the whole system.

None of this is insurmountable, but it's also hard to see any particular benefits for the effort and extra complexity required.

Comment: ok. i will look on some other approach to deliver my app